# What changes should I do to run cocos2d apps in iOS 7?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ios7

I am trying to build an cocos2d app in iOS 7, but i have some problems.

```
[string drawInRect:drawArea withFont:uifont lineBreakMode:linebreaks[definition.lineBreakMode] alignment:alignments[definition.alignment]];
```

warning : 'drawInRect:withFont:lineBreakMode:alignment:' is deprecated in iOS 7 - Use -drawInRect:withAttributes:

```
CGSize boundingSize = CGSizeMake(CGFLOAT_MAX, CGFLOAT_MAX);
CGSize dim = [string sizeWithFont:uifont
          constrainedToSize:boundingSize
             lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
```

warning : 'sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:' is deprecated in iOS 7.0 - Use -boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:

```
AudioSessionGetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OtherAudioIsPlaying, &varSize, &isPlaying);
```

warning :'AudioSessionGetProperty' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 7.0

```
director_.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
```

warning: 'wantsFullScreenLayout' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 7.0

```
-(void) setAccelerometerEnabled:(BOOL)enabled
{
    if( enabled != _accelerometerEnabled ) {
        _accelerometerEnabled = enabled;
        if( _isRunning ) {
            if( enabled )
                [[UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer] setDelegate:(id<UIAccelerometerDelegate>)self];
            else
                [[UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer] setDelegate:nil];
        }
    }
}

-(void) setAccelerometerInterval:(float)interval
{
    [[UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer] setUpdateInterval:interval];
}
```

warning : 'UIAccelerometer' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 5.0 - UIAccelerometer has been replaced by the CoreMotion framework

Can someone help me to solve these problems?

Comment: check cocos2d on github, dev branch. with any luck those things have already been fixed